# npm install failing over random packages

Tags: angular, npm

While trying to implement compression for my Angular app, the commands "npm install" and "npm update" keep failing on random packages.

The following packages were affected"

- @angular-devkit/build-angular
- '@jsdevtools/coverage-istanbul-loader@3.0.5' is not in the npm registry.
- '@ngtools/webpack@10.1.0-next.4' is not in the npm registry.

I tried using "npm cache clean --force" but without success

Comment: Npm has issues today..

Answer (score 0):

Try Deleting the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file and after that try `npm install` again